# Что это за вид модального окна? Помогите разобраться!

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

[Ссылка на пример всплывающего окна](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/the%20new%20tab?_category=extensions)

Здравствуйте,

При переходе на ссылку там есть кнопка "Установить" при нажатии появляется окошко с вопросом, которое можно передвигать по всему экрану, даже вне контейнера. Что это за вид модального окна или как создать такое самому?

Спасибо.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку "Установить" в Маркетплэйсе Гугла появляется не модальное окно, а "алёрт" браузера. У меня его передвигать нельзя.

Comment: А что у вас за браузер?

Comment: Десктопный Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Если вас интересует реализация любых перетаскиваемых элементов, ищите по ключу **drag-and-drop**. Для js существует много удачных реализаций-библиотек, например [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

Кроме того, возможность перетаскивания элементов частично встроена в HTML5: читайте [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/187582/) и [тут](https://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/dnd/basics/).